# Firefox startup glitch

Tags: firefox

When I boot into ubuntu 20.04 with laptop and secondary monitor as primary, I open Firefox and it's minimized.. I go to maximize it and it's not happening..I can maximize it if I move my mouse to the top of the screen(where firefox isn't visable) but it works? Doesn't happen EVERY time but often enough.

Comment: Hello. Can you give a way that this can be duplicated? As written there is not really anything here to work with. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah sorry David, I've been restarting my laptop in hopes to get a video of what's going on.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, Just noting to be able to help with.

Comment: Edit your post and make it more clear. It is currently not clear. Describe stepwise what happens, what you try and what you expect to happen in a way that someone else could reproduces on his/her system.